# High CPU load on docker logs -f

Tags: docker

I have multiple docker instance running and I want to push the log outputs to a GUI.

I wrote python script which basically does

```
docker logs $containerId --tail 50 -f
```

for each container.

The result is nice and it works fine, but I have a very high cpu load from dockerd.

What can I do to prevent the high load? Are there better ways to get the log output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your docker file and cpu usage by docker

Comment: There a several docker files. One example is: https://github.com/StellarKit/stellarkit-bitcoin/blob/master/bitcoin-docker/Dockerfile

I only can see in terminal (top) that dockerd has >90% cpu load

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Docker also saves the output to a file:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' $containerId
```

Then I just tail this file:

```
tail -f $path
```